# Почему обе кнопки не могут работать одновременно?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите пожалуйста с примером. После загрузки страницы, нажимая на одну из кнопок (плюс и крестик) https://codepen.io/rusl10/pen/mYeerL  она отрабатывает свое действие, но другая перестает работать.Как, что нужно сделать с обработчиками, чтобы все работало?

```
    let add = document.querySelector('.btn-add');
```

```js
let add = document.querySelector('.btn-add');
let del = document.querySelector('.btn-delete');
let parent = document.querySelector('.choices__wrap');


add.addEventListener('click', function addHandler() {
  let lastForClone = document.querySelector('.choices__row.last');
  let clone = lastForClone.cloneNode(true);
  lastForClone.removeChild(document.querySelector('.btn-add'));
  lastForClone.removeChild(document.querySelector('.btn-delete'));
  lastForClone.classList.remove('last');
  clone.querySelector('.btn-add').addEventListener('click', addHandler);
  parent.appendChild(clone);
});

del.addEventListener('click', function addHand() {
  let lastForClone = document.querySelector('.choices__row.last');
  let clone = lastForClone.cloneNode(true);
  let rows = document.querySelectorAll('.choices__row');
  parent.removeChild(document.querySelector('.choices__row.last'));
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[rows.length - 2].remove();
  }
  console.log(clone);
  clone.querySelector('.btn-delete').addEventListener('click', addHand);
  parent.appendChild(clone);
});
```

```css
.choices__row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 27px;
}

.choices__default {
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 980px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 4px solid #2f403c;
  padding: 17px 0 17px 30px;
}

.btn-delete {
  width: 36px;
  height: 35px;
  background: url(https://svgshare.com/i/Cur.svg) no-repeat center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-add {
  width: 37px;
  height: 37px;
  background: url(https://svgshare.com/i/Cuz.svg) no-repeat center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="choices__wrap">
  <div class="choices__row">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter choice" class="choices__default" required="">
  </div>
  <div class="choices__row">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter choice" class="choices__default" required="">
  </div>
  <div class="choices__row last">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter choice" class="choices__default" required="">
    <div class="btn-delete"></div>
    <div class="btn-add"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Весь код по ссылке

Comment: объясните логику, на кой брать последнюю строку в которой есть лишние кнопки, клонировать ее, а потом удалять эти кнопки и т.п.?
вы сделайте лучше скрытый див с нужной разметкой тогда уж и его клонируйте. Или вообще на уровне верстки отделите эти кнопки в отдельный блок, но чтобы визуально оно осталось таким же.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let add = 'btn-add';    // класс кнопки добавить
let del = 'btn-delete'; // класс кнопки удалить
let parent = document.querySelector('.choices__wrap');

document.addEventListener('click',function(e){

   if(e.target && e.target.classList.contains(add)){
      let lastForClone = document.querySelector('.choices__row.last');
      let clone = lastForClone.cloneNode(true);
      lastForClone.removeChild(document.querySelector('.btn-add'));
      lastForClone.removeChild(document.querySelector('.btn-delete'));
      lastForClone.classList.remove('last');
      parent.appendChild(clone);
   }
  
  if(e.target && e.target.classList.contains(del)){
     let lastForClone = document.querySelector('.choices__row.last');
     let clone = lastForClone.cloneNode(true);
     let rows = document.querySelectorAll('.choices__row');
     parent.removeChild(document.querySelector('.choices__row.last'));
     for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      rows[rows.length-2].remove();
     }
     parent.appendChild(clone);
  }
});
```

```css
.choices__row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 27px;
}

.choices__default {
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 980px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 4px solid #2f403c;
  padding: 17px 0 17px 30px;
}

.btn-delete {
  width: 36px;
  height: 35px;
  background: url(https://svgshare.com/i/Cur.svg) no-repeat center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-add {
  width: 37px;
  height: 37px;
  background: url(https://svgshare.com/i/Cuz.svg) no-repeat center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="choices__wrap">
  <div class="choices__row">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Enter choice" class="choices__default" required="">
  </div> 
  <div class="choices__row">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter choice" class="choices__default" required="">
  </div>
  <div class="choices__row last"> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter choice" class="choices__default" required="">
    <div class="btn-delete"></div>
    <div class="btn-add"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: не хотите текстом написать, в чем был не прав автор вопроса?

Comment: @teran проблема была в том, что динамические элементы не имеют тех же слушателей что и существующие элементы, надо было либо при клике на кнопку передавать как-то оба слушателя, либо вот так. Есть ещё способы, которые мне не известны. Ещё, знаю минус данного способа - если на странице много слушателей то может немного подвисать (нашему "взору" это вряд ли будет заметно) так как загружается весь dom при клике.
Это как-раз один из примеров реализации принципа делегирования, когда вместо кучи слушателей подобных, вешается только один на родительский элемент